# get top most result of one of the table in join

Tags: sql, oracle, oracle11g

I need to 3 join three tables  `TM, TA, MS` - TA has multiple records for each row in TM I need to get the `last row from TA` for ever row in TM based a field called status which is highest for the newest record

This is my query:

```
select * from TABLE1 MS RIGHT OUTER JOIN
TABLE2 TM ON MS.CID = TM.CID
LEFT OUTER JOIN TABLE3 TA ON TM.EID=TA.EID;
```

Comment: Mixing RIGHT JOIN with LEFT JOIN... Who do you expect to understand that query? Most people have problem enough with LEFT JOIN alone... (If you want to write code that can be maintained, stick to LEFT JOIN only!)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One method uses `row_number()`:

```
select *
from TABLE1 MS JOIN
     TABLE2 TM
     ON MS.CID = TM.CID JOIN
     (SELECT TA.*, ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY EID ORDER BY STATUS DESC) as seqnum
      FROM TABLE3 TA
     ) TA
     ON TM.EID = TA.EID AND seqnum = 1;
```

Your question says nothing about unmatched records, so I removed the outer joins.  These should only be used when you intend to keep unmatched records (and most people prefer `LEFT JOIN` to `RIGHT JOIN` for this purpose).